# cURL Warning and I'm already using --output, what can I try next?

Tags: curl

I've been working on this searching Google for 4 hours and can't find anything. I'm trying to download an Excel document from an internal website. This cURL command used to work. But something changed and now I get that dreaded error

Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output " to save to a file.

`curl -i -j -c cookies.txt -X GET https://app.domain.com -L --next -i -b cookies.txt -d "username=myuser&password=mypassword&x=0&y=0&vhost=standard" -X POST https://app.domain.com/my.policy --next -i -b cookies.txt -X GET https://app.domain.com/app/page -L --next -b cookies.txt -d "year=2023" -X POST https://app.domain.com/app/page/rest/export/excel/year -o "%temp%\data.xlsx"`

If I replace the -o option with the > redirect it almost works. It writes to my disk. It won't open in Excel initially. If I open it in Notepad++ I can see the top of the file contains the complete html document, plus what looked like raw data, and that the download is opening an iFrame. If I delete everything from the HTTP header to the  end tag and then save it, Excel did recognize the raw data and opened the file correctly.

How do I get cURL to download only the Excel data and save it to the file, without including the html documents in the beginning of the file? I've tried so many permutations of -o -O --output --referer -e, and nothing works. Thanks.